# Getting error on adding class in admin.site.register function

Tags: django

i am getting this error when i try to add ProductoAdmin class in admin.site.register function.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Marca, Producto
# Register your models here.

class ProductoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nombre', 'precio', 'nuevo', 'marca')
    list_editable = ["precio"]
    search_fields = ["nombre"]

admin.site.register(Marca)
admin.site.register(Producto, ProductoAdmin)
```

Error

```
<class 'app.admin.ProductoAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'nuevo', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductoAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'app.Producto'.
```

**FIXED**
**The option 'nuevo' didn't exist in Producto model **

Comment: can you add your model Producto to the question?

Comment: if your issue is fixed please create an answer to your question